# Lost permission to modify external storage from PC after rooting my tablet

Tags: rooting, root-access, usb, permissions, mediatek

I have a highly secured proprietary tablet I was able to gain root access to. It's a mediatek device, I used mtk-su to root it. It has 32gb of memory, 8gb allocated to the system, and the rest allocated as external storage.

Prior to rooting, I was able to plug in to my PC and access external storage with FULL read/write permissions.

After rooting, when I plug in to my PC, it now gives me read-only permissions. I have termux installed on the tablet with SU permission, so I can modify any system properties. However, I can't figure out what needs to be done to re-mount the partition as read/write.

I tried pushing the files with adb, and it says the tablet is unauthorized. I really don't want to have to use adb anyways. Any ideas how I can re-gain read/write access??

EDIT:
@Robert
My apologies! I just looked in the root directory to get the EXACT path name of this folder. Here's where it is:

```
root/mnt/sdcard1 **This is the exposed path when I plug into PC.**
```

There is also an sdcard

```
root/mnt/sdcard **This isn't the directory in question.**
```

@IrfanLatif
My apologies for not being correct on the semantics. I'm a web developer, and android programming/modification is a new thing to me. I'm trying/learning. I know it is is read only because, after plugging in to the PC, I can no longer copy to the drive (or w/e it would be called here, not sure?), or modify anything inside it. It gives error, saying I only have read access.

Thanks

Comment: What path of the device is exposed to you via MTP? What are the access permissions of that directory? Note: Usually "external storage" in Android is an external SD-card, the user data partition that also contains the `/sdcard` is usually named "internal storage" or user data partition.

Comment: *"I can't figure out what needs to be done to re-mount the partition as read/write"*. There's no partition mounted. MTP is file transfer protocol. // *"when I plug in to my PC, it now gives me read-only permissions"*. How do you know that it's read-only? What happens when you try to write a file?

Comment: @Robert Sorry about that, I'm relatively new to the android world. I edited the question. The exact path is **root/mnt/sdcard1** That's what I usually have read/write access to when I plug into PC.

Comment: problem is selinux, `mtk-su` probably ended up with stronger restrictions than regular shell